# When I go to run the API, I get errors looking for examples

Tags: api

Civi version 4.6.3.
When I access the API, it loads but with errors related to the examples.

This is an IIS server.

> Warning:
>   scandir(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\civicrmapi/v3/examples,C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\civicrmapi/v3/examples):
>   The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in
>   CRM_Admin_Page_APIExplorer->run() (line 55 of
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Admin\Page\APIExplorer.php).
>       Warning: scandir(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\civicrmapi/v3/examples):
>   failed to open dir: No such file or directory in
>   CRM_Admin_Page_APIExplorer->run() (line 55 of
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Admin\Page\APIExplorer.php).
>       Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in CRM_Admin_Page_APIExplorer->run() (line 55 of
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Admin\Page\APIExplorer.php).
>       Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in CRM_Admin_Page_APIExplorer->run() (line 55 of
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Admin\Page\APIExplorer.php).

There appears to be a missing slash in the warnings between the civicrm and api folders.

If I edit APIExplorer.php and add either `\` or `\/` the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git history shows this bug to have been [already fixed on 6th June 2015](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/988e67ca92957bbce884a80c075e813093b851d8). Please upgrade to the latest version of CiviCRM and try again.